# twig doesn't load template at all

Tags: php, twig

I'm new to twig, and I'm having a problem in the very first steps.
twig doesn't load any template, and it returns a blank page.
my files' map look like this:

```
-app/
---vendor/
---cache/
---templates/
------- home.html
---hi.php
```

hi.php :

```
<?php

        require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

        class twiger
        {
                private static $twig;
                public static function twig() {
                        $templatedir = __DIR__.'templates';
                        if ( ! isset(self::$twig)) {
                                $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array($templatedir));
                                self::$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
                        }
                        return self::$twig;
                }
        }
    $msg = "Hello World";
        $tw = twiger::twig();
        echo $tw->render("home.html", array('msg' => $msg));
?>
```

and home.html:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title>hello</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <h4>the meassage is:<h4>
                <H2> {{ msg }} </H2>

        </body>
</html>
```

I tried to set debug to true but nothing happened
I checked out the the permissions
in the browser's console it shows "500 internal server error" 
I'm on fedora workstation 27
php 7.2.5
twig 2.4.8

I searched around for a solution, but all the similar questions were about a typo or misleading directory and so on, which I already checked.

any help will be great

> Update:[SOLVED] I found out that the problem was because of the missing
>   "composer.json" and "composer.lock" files. After I included them in
>   the same path, it has worked.

Comment: Check your error logs for detail error description.

Comment: I suppose `__DIR__` has no trailing slash so your path is incorrect.

Comment: yes, i found the error, the require_once() function doesn't have permission to access /usr/share/php .. should i change the permission of this directory or is there an alternative solution?

Comment: Where does `/usr/share/php` come from? It's a system folder, how it is involved?

Comment: this is the error: PHP Warning:  include(/var/www/html/app/vendor/autoload.php failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/app/hi.php on line 3

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/app/hi.php on line 3

Comment: Change to `require_once __DIR__. '/vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: Thanks, I found out the Solution and updated the question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I couldn't mark the Question as answered without posting a separate post, so : the problem was about the missing "composer.json" and "composer.lock" files, which were generated in another path. after adding them to the project's directory along with vendor folder, twig has worked.